# How can you get more than one $or condition into a single mongodb find() operation?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, find, logical-or

I've got an operation where I'm trying to limit results on a collection using the `$or` operator, however I have more than one field that needs to utilize this functionality.

See query below:

```
db.items.find({//"isDeleted":false,
    "$or":[
        {"$and":[{"passages.fleschKincaid.readingEase":{"$gte":90}}]},
        {"$and":[{"passages.fleschKincaid.readingEase":{"$gte":60}},{"passages.fleschKincaid.readingEase":{"$lte":70}}]},
        {"$and":[{"passages.fleschKincaid.readingEase":{"$gte":50}},{"passages.fleschKincaid.readingEase":{"$lte":60}}]}
    ],
    "$or":[{"$and": [{"contentBanks":{$in: element.statusIds}}]}]})
```

The first condition loops through and adds on gte/lte operators based on certain conditions, and the second or condition I've used here is within a for loop that pushes on an additional `$and` for each new `contentBank`. Each one only needs to satisfy one of the conditions to show as a result, but `contentBank` and `passages.fleschKincaid.readingEase` are mutually exclusive so they can't be grouped together in the same $or group.

i.e. - if I have an item, for it to meet my conditions in the above example, it needs both a `readingEase` score of let's say 55, AND have a `contentBank` in `statusIds`. It needs to meet both conditions, but check the `$or`'s separately.

What I end up with is a query that overwrites the written conditions and treats it as one big `$or`, returning results that might match one `contentBank` but not be within the `readingEase` range.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm writing this with javascript, mongoose, and mongodb. If you know of a way to get the query to treat them separately that would be great.

p.s. - I'm trying to avoid it getting to chock-full of `$and` operators, but if that's the only way to do this, I can find a way to create a whole new object and add it in. The only issue with that is the complexity increases quite a bit because the pipeline operators are all built dynamically - so the additional `$and` operator wrapping everything would require a solid amount of changes/overhead to get working.

Comment: `{"$and":[{"passages.fleschKincaid.readingEase":{"$gte":90}}]},` - you dont need an $and operator here. `{"$and": [{"contentBanks":{$in: element.statusIds}}]}` - again the $and is not needed.

Comment: `{"$and":[{"passages.fleschKincaid.readingEase":{"$gte":60}},{"passages.fleschKincaid.readingEase":{"$lte":70}}]},
        {"$and":[{"passages.fleschKincaid.readingEase":{"$gte":50}},{"passages.fleschKincaid.readingEase":{"$lte":60}}]}` - you can build this part using a single $and. See the usage of [$and operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/).

Comment: @prasad_ this doesn't work. From the docs: "`$and` performs a logical AND operation on an array of one or more expressions `(<expression1>, <expression2>, and so on)` and selects the documents that satisfy all the expressions."

In this case if I have a score of 55, that only satisfies one of the conditions. But I still need that result to display. Hence why those `$and` operations are wrapped in an `$or` operation.

Comment: @prasad_ also those single argument `$and` ops are still wrapped in an `$and` because it's part of a dynamically built query that doesn't recognize whether it has 1 or 100 operands in it. So theoretically it could have many more than just one in it, so the structure is built that way.